Pop-up consistently centered below an element?
I am coding a browser game, which has a bunch of buttons. In order to explain the rules, I am using some pop-ups that appear when the mouse hovers on the button. These pop-ups have a little triangle that point towards the button they are related to, as a pseudo-element.
In the example below I am showing the pop-up on two different buttons. While the popup is mostly centered for the "Clear" button, it is not centered for the "Hint" button.


button {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 var(--stripeColorDark);
    padding: 10px;
    color: var(--textColor);
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hint-button {
    width: 300px;
}

.clear-button {
    width: 100px;
}

/* Popup container */
.popup-container {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup-text {
    position: absolute;

    padding: 10px;
    top: 105%;
    
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;

    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #303030;
    
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

    z-index: 1;
}

.popup-container:hover .popup-text  {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.popup-text::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    
    border: 5px solid #303030;
    border-color: transparent transparent #303030 #303030;
    
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
<div class="popup-container keep-target" id="hint-button-container">
    <button id="hint-button" tabindex="-1" class="hint-button keep-target">Hint</button>
    <div class="popup-text popup-hint keep-target">Reveal a letter of your choice.</div>
</div>

<div class="popup-container keep-target" id="clear-button-container">
    <button id="hint-button" tabindex="-1" class="clear-button keep-target">Clear</button>
    <div class="popup-text popup-hint keep-target">Clear the board.</div>
</div>



Is there a way I can consistently center the pop-up and the triangle below the button, no matter its size?

You have to deal with CSS width: fit-content;
then you can use to center your .popup-text element...
  left      : 50%;
  transform : translateX(-50%);



.popup-container {   
  position    : relative;
  cursor      : pointer;
  width       : fit-content;
  font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
  color       : black;
  font-size   : 16px;

  & > button {
    cursor        : pointer;
    min-width     : 10em;
    width         : fit-content;  /* <--- changed  */
    background    : lightblue;
    border        : none;
    box-shadow    : .2em .2em 0 lightslategray;
    padding       : .4em 0;
    margin        : .3em;
    border-radius : .7em;
    font-size     : inherit;
    }
  & > button.hint-button {
    width : 24em; 
    }
  }

.popup-text {  /* The actual popup (appears on top) */
  position      : absolute;
  padding       : .6em;
  top           : 105%;
  left          : 50%;                /* <--- changed  */
  transform     : translateX(-50%);   /* <--- changed  */
  height        : fit-content;        /* <--- changed  */
  max-width     : 40%;                /* <--- changed  */
  border-radius : .6em;
  background    : #303030;
  color         : white;
  text-align    : center;
  opacity       : 0;
  visibility    : hidden;
  transition    : all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index       : 1;
  }
.popup-container:hover .popup-text  {
  opacity    : 1;
  visibility : visible;
  }
.popup-text::after {
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  bottom           : 100%;
  left             : 50%;
  border           : .5em solid;
  border-color     : transparent transparent #303030 #303030;
  transform-origin : center 0;
  transform        : translateY(1.6em) rotate(135deg) ;
  box-sizing       : border-box;
  }
<div class="popup-container">
  <button id="hint-button" tabindex="-1" class="hint-button">Hint</button>
  <div class="popup-text">Reveal a letter of your choice.</div>
</div>

<div class="popup-container">
  <button id="hint-button" tabindex="-1" class="clear-button">Clear</button>
  <div class="popup-text">Clear the board.</div>
</div>




Thank you! That's exactly what I needed!
